# How can I disable that "Display all possibilities" and --More-- stuff in bash?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

In my shell, <kbd>l</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> completes like:

```
wim@wim-zenbook:~$ l
Display all 135 possibilities? (y or n)
```

There's a prompt to answer `y` or `n` which is annoying, and it pages through with `--More--` which is also annoying.  How can we make it just show possibilities without the nags?

Using gnome-terminal on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I read man pages of bash and was able to get the behaviour I wanted by adding the following lines in the file `~/.inputrc`

```
set completion-query-items 0
set page-completions off
```

Comment: Looks much simpler than my answer ;) Apart from that I forget that part of your question with `--more--`...

Comment: Regarding ```page-completions```. From the manual ```"If set to On, readline uses an internal more-like pager to display a screenful of  possible  completions at a time."``` Arguably, a better option may be to turn this to On and prevent output scrolling off screen.

Comment: @TonyBarganski Hard disagree, having this on causes the very problem I want to resolve: that is, not interrupting me to press an additional key. With that on, I see `--More--`.

Answer (score 4):

I found that in bash's changelog:

> If the rl_completion_query_items is set to a value < 0, readline never
>   asks the user whether or not to view the possible completions.

To set this *readline* variable use

```
set completion-query-items [value]
```

This is an excerpt from `man bash`:

> A variable may be set in the *inputrc* file (...)
>
> **completion-query-items (100)**
>                 This determines when the user is queried about viewing the number of possible completions  generated  by
>                 the possible-completions command.  It may be set to any integer value greater than or equal to zero.  If
>                 the number of possible completions is greater than or equal to the value of this variable, the  user  is
>                 asked whether or not he wishes to view them; otherwise they are simply listed on the terminal.

As according to the doc you can't set this to a negative value, so I would suggest a very large number instead.

Comment: The [bash docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Init-File-Syntax) now read: `completion-query-items
The number of possible completions that determines when the user is asked whether the list of possibilities should be displayed. If the number of possible completions is greater than or equal to this value, Readline will ask whether or not the user wishes to view them; otherwise, they are simply listed. This variable must be set to an integer value greater than or equal to 0. A negative value means Readline should never ask. The default limit is 100.`